# Ionic VueJs capacitor plugin native audio

Tags: vue.js, ionic-framework, capacitor

I know that maybe is a stupid question but i can't find anything anywhere...
I'm trying to use a capacitor plugin in Vue js called "native audio" to build a music player. The problem is that i can't find any documentation on how to use it in Vue.(https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/native-audio).
Maybe someone used it and have an example...
I'm using Capacitor, and Ionic vue js.
Thanks

Comment: look at the react documentation, it is basically the same - https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/community#react

Comment: What do you want to do?

Comment: Building a music player using a capacitor plugin + vue.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Validate if this public project based on Ionic + Vue.js could be useful to you.

It contains the following features:

- record audio ios
- record audio Android
- playback audio Android
- delete audio Android
- set the duration of the recording
- listen for "recordingFinished" event to get the path of the recording and the duration
- playback audio ios - (in progress)
- delete audio ios - (in progress)

Apparently, it reach to do everything without using the plugin, only native HTML5 capabilities.

GitHub project link: https://github.com/aaronksaunders/ionic-html5-audio-vue

Best regards.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i already done it in HTML5. The problem is that i need to customise the "Player Controls" when the screen is locked.(like image of current song, play next song...things like that).